# how to detect filename in current java script code runing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, browser

I want dynamically send current filename from running script location

for example :

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></scritp>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function(){
    $data = [];
    $.getJSON("data.php",{ajax_sending_filename : FILE_NAME},  
    function(response){
        $data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    });
});
```

I need to dynamically get current filename and replace it with FILE_NAME :

```
 $.getJSON("data.php",{ajax_sending_filename : 'index' //FILE_NAME},
```

Please suggest a way that will work in all browsers.

Thanks for your help :-)

**EDIT :**

I cant't use windows.location because using MVC and location differ by filename.

Comment: What does the page URL look like?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I cant't use windows.location because using mvc and location diffrent by filename

Comment: Store  the file name in a JS var using PHP and then use it as wish.

Comment: @lshettyl no i can't using php to save file name, this script running independed server side, i want get file name from client side

Comment: The only information you have on the client side is the page URL. If you need anything else, you must do it server side.

Comment: @lshettyl i think best way, using current route instance of filename

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the current filename in jquery:

```
$(location).attr('pathname');  // the filename (ie: index.php)
```

If you want the full url do this:

```
$(location).attr('href');      // the full url
```

If you put the filename in a variable you can do anything you want with it...

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj0zb9uu/
Hope that helps you...

Comment: I cant't use windows.location because using mvc and location diffrent by filename